# The ID can not be a writable

Tags: reactjs, foreach

I create a deltask in Slice and the addtask and in addtask function i add to the object id to distinguish when the user clicks on X button to deleted but there is problem in decreasing the id by one becuase it is connected with index in map loop and the below error occur on line 17 in Tasks function  Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '#'

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import AddTask from './AddTask';
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { delTask } from '../redux/TaskSlice';

const  Tasks = () => {
  let {todos} = useSelector(state => state.task);
  const[todo,editTodo]=useState([]);
  const  Dispatch=useDispatch();
  

  const hanndleDelTask=(e,id)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  todos=todos.filter((todoo)=>(todoo.id !== id));
  Dispatch(delTask(todos));
  todos.forEach(todoo => {
    todoo.id=todoo.id-1; 
  });
 }

  useEffect(()=>{
  editTodo(todos);
 },[todos]); 


  return (

      <React.Fragment>
      
      <AddTask/>
      {todo.map((value,index)=>( 
        
      <div key={index} className='taskDiv'>
        <div>
        <h3>{value.task}</h3>
       <h4>{value.time}</h4>
        </div>
       <button onClick={ (e)=>hanndleDelTask(e,index)} >X</button>
      </div>
      
   )
   )}
    </React.Fragment>

     
   
  )
}

export default Tasks







import { addTask } from '../redux/TaskSlice';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch  } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './Header';

const  AddTask = () => {


    const Dispatch =useDispatch();
    const [task,setTask]=useState("");
    const [time,setTime]=useState("");
    let [id,setId]=useState(-1);
    const [isRemove,setRemove]=useState(true);
    const handdleAddTask = (e)=> {
      e.preventDefault();
      setId(id+=1);
      Dispatch(addTask({task,time,id,isRemove}));
      setTask('');
      setTime('');
    }
  return (
     <React.Fragment >

  <Header/>
    <form className='form' onSubmit={handdleAddTask}>
      <div className='formDivs'>
        <label >Task</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setTask(e.target.value)}} value={task}/>
      </div>
      <div className='formDivs'>
        <label >Date && Time</label>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setTime(e.target.value)}} value={time}/>
      </div>
      
      <button type="Submit" >ADD</button>
    </form>
 
    </React.Fragment >

  )
}

export default AddTask




import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const TaskSlice=createSlice({

    name:'task',
    initialState:{
        todos:[],
    },
    reducers:{

      addTask  : (state,action) => {
        state.todos=[...state.todos , action.payload];
        console.log('state',state.todos)

        },
        delTask :(state,action) =>{
            state.todos= action.payload
            console.log('action',action.payload)
            console.log(current(state));
        }
    }
    
});
export const {addTask,delTask}=TaskSlice.actions
export default TaskSlice.reducer
```

Comment: what are the data coming in todos array?

Comment: try with decrement   todoo.id--; instead of  todoo.id=todoo.id-1;

Comment: add some code sandbox snippets.

Comment: Your matching two different type of arrays todo and todos

Comment: i Try the todoo.id-- not work

Comment: todos array have the task and time and id

Comment: and todo array has no effect on the function it is just for printing todos on screen

Comment: Maybe todo id and index quite different. So you have try passing with value.id from todos map instead of index

Answer (score 0):

todos is coming from useSelector, so you are trying to write directly into the redux state.

> todos.forEach(todoo => {
> todoo.id=todoo.id-1;
> });

Use dispatch to update the redux store.